Why did Mistral choose these animals to compare with the sun in her poem "Dos Himnos"?
Dos Himnos (Two Hymns) is a poem by Gabriela Mistral in praise of the original Indian inhabitants of Latin America. The first part, Sol del Trópico, is a hymn in praise of the sun of the tropics. In it, she invokes the sun, addressing it as various animals. Is there any reason she picked these particular animals?
Following are excerpts from this poem where she refers to the sun in terms of animals. The English is taken from Ursula Le Guin's translation, Two Hymns — I: Tropic Sun.
From the first stanza:

Faisán rojo cuando levantas
y cuando medios, faisán blanco,
Red pheasant as you rise,
at noon, white pheasant,

——

Rafael de las marchas nuestras,
lebrel de oro de nuestros pasos,
Archangel of our courses,
golden greyhound of our passes,

From the second stanza:

ciervo blanco o enrojecido,
siempre herido, nunca cazado...
white stag, bloodstained stag,
forever wounded, never hunted down...

From the third stanza:

quetzal de fuego emblanquecido
que cría y nutre pueblos mágicos;
llama pasmado en rutas blancas
guiando llamas alucinados...
Quetzal of bleached fire
that bears and feeds the magic peoples:
llama of ecstasy that leads your flock
in trance along white roads...

From the fourth stanza:

¡Pájaro Roc, plumón que empolla
dos orientes desenfrenados!
Roc-bird, plumed breast hatching
two uncontrollable Orients!

From the fifth stanza:

tórtolas blancas en bandada,
maná que baja sin doblarnos.
a whirl of white doves,
manna lightly descending.


I don't have a specific answer for this poem but this long article explains why the poet was so drawn to nature (plants and animals after she visited as a child a park (as in manor house-type park) in Chile. As of page 11, she explains her enchantment: https://www.memoriachilena.gob.cl/archivos2/pdfs/mc0013125.pdf

I think that the most convincing interpretation of this poem that I have seen is given by Oscar Hahn in an article in the November 2024 issue of the literary magazine Altazor.
Hahn writes:

En el poema pueden distinguirse dos partes. En la primera, usa una
variedad de apelativos para nombrar al astro rey. Son de naturaleza
zoomórfica:  faisán, lebrel, ciervo, quetzal, llama, tórtola, pájaro
Roc, lagarto; y los tiñe con los colores del sol y de sus rayos a
distintas horas del día: rojo, dorado, blanco, tornasol.

which I translate as:

You can divide the poem into two parts. In the first, she [Mistral]
uses a variety of appellations to name the sun. They are animal in
nature: pheasant, greyhound, deer, quetzal, llama, turtledove, the
Roc, lizard; and she colors them with the colors of the sun and its
rays at different times of the day: red, gold, white, iridescent.

Some of the animal-color combinations are reasonably obvious, others demand more interpretation. To go through the full list would be a huge job, which is why I propose to leave this answer open as  a community wiki, so that anyone with inspiration can add their thoughts.

In the first stanza, we have the first mention of an animal:

Faisán rojo cuando levantas 
y cuando medias, faisán blanco

"A red pheasant when you rise / and when you're half-way, a white pheasant". This is clearly referring to the sunrise: the sun appears red at first, and then pales as it rises. The pheasant is a gamebird that hides under cover. When it is driven it ascends from the ground almost vertically, which seems an apt metaphor for the sun rising above the horizon.
From the second stanza:

Rafael de las marchas nuestras, 
lebrel de oro de nuestros pasos,

"The archangel Raphael of our paths / golden greyhound of our steps". The sun is fully risen, and is above us like the angels. It's color is now golden, and it is moving across the sky rapidly, the speed of its motion symbolised by the racing-dog, the greyhound.
From the third stanza:

ciervo blanco o enrojecido, 
siempre herido, nunca cazado...

From the fourth stanza:

quetzal de fuego emblanquecido 
que cría y nutre pueblos mágicos; 
llama pasmado en rutas blancas 
guiando llamas alucinados... 

From the fifth stanza:

¡Pájaro Roc, plumón que empolla 
dos orientes desenfrenados!

From the sixth stanza:

tórtolas blancas en bandada, 
maná que baja sin doblarnos.

And finally from the seventh stanza:

Sobre tendal de salamandras 
duermen y sueñan sus cuerpos santos.

"On a canopy of salamanders / their holy bodies dream and sleep". As well as being the name of an amphibian, salamanders are mythical lizards associated with fire. The sun is now setting, symbolised by the fire-lizards going to sleep and dreaming.
